# flash netstream appendBytes and .mp4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video-streaming, netstream, osmf

Can I use `NetStream.appendBytes()` with an mp4 file? There seems to be several options, but I'm not sure if any of them work:

1. osmf HTTPNetStream - http://sourceforge.net/adobe/osmf/svn/2487/tree/osmf/trunk/framework/OSMF/org/osmf/net/httpstreaming/HTTPNetStream.as#l191
2. flowplayer psuedoNetStream which apparently require server side manipulation.
   http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/streaming/mp4-pseudostreaming.html

I'm looking for a client side solution i.e. It will get the byte array from the server on its own.

I think `appendBytes()` supports only flv but is there a way to manipulate that using FLVtag?
It may be a problem to parse the metadata of the mp4. I think I need to know how to append fragments of the mp4.